# Strange behavior of left arrow key in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I saw someone else had this question for Excel 2010, but it was never properly answered and I will be more specific as to what is happening.

In Excel 2013, only when I am working on a PROTECTED sheet, if I have cell A2 selected and try to use the left arrow key, instead of stopping at A1, it cycles the selection all the way over to AU2!

I've also tried the suggestion to simply use the "home" key to go to the beginning of the row, however, it does not take me to A2, it takes me to E1.

Can anyone help with this??

Comment: Hello and welcome to SU! This is a duplicate question (as you've pointed out).  SU [doesn't like duplicates](http://superuser.com/help/duplicates). :) If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question, please earn some [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and place [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate solution:

Go to Review>Unprotect Sheet

Then right click the sheet tab at the bottom of the screen and choose View Code

You'll get a screen that has two panels on the left. On the bottom panel, in "Enable Selection" choose "0 - xlNoRestriction"

Hit the save button and close this screen

Re-protect your sheet

This will allow any cell to be selected even if it is locked (but you will get an error message if you try to edit a locked cell)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have some locked cells in your worksheet. This means that when the sheet is protected, if the protector does not check the "select locked cells" option then once the sheet is protected users will not be able to select the locked cells which can create unusual jumps when using the movement arrows to navigate the sheet.

For example, if you were to lock every cell in columns **C** to **XFD** then pressing right from **A1** whould navigate as follows

```
A1 --> A2 --> B1 --> B2 --> C1 ...
```

The solutions are:
1. Check the box "select locked cells" when protecting the sheet
2. Unlock all/necessary cells on the sheet before protecting